# Can't drop null values in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nan, missing-data

I got this dataset that when values are null it has the symbol `-`

At first I thought it wasn't a problem, so to drop these rows I did:

```
df_c = df[df != '-']
```

But it didn't actually drop the rows, it put instead a NaN in place of `-`

Then I did:

```
df_c = df_c[df_c.notnull()]
```

But it doesn't work, and it gives me back `-` again. 
What am I doind wrong?

Comment: Can you add the language in your labels? Python?

Comment: Sorry I totally forgot, yes it's Python

Comment: try `del df[df != '-']` alternatively, can you give an example of the df data structure?

Comment: In 2nd operation you are using `df` instead of `df_c`.  Use `df_c.dropna()`

Comment: @Sociopath I know but even doing df_c it doesn't work

Comment: @TomosWilliams if I do that, it gives me this error:  `[500 rows x 12 columns]' is an invalid key`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) + [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

You can mask with a Boolean dataframe, then use `dropna`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, '-', '-', 4, '-'],
                   'B': ['A', 'B', '-', 'C', '-'],
                   'C': [0.5, '-', '-', 1.5, 2.5]})

df = df.mask(df == '-').dropna()

print(df)

   A  B    C
0  1  A  0.5
3  4  C  1.5
```

By default, `dropna` drops rows (`axis=0`) where *any* value is null (`how='any'`). You can amend these parameters as appropriate.

**Note:** This is functionally identical to `df = df[df != '-'].dropna()`. Though, from a cosmetic perspective, the *intent* of `mask` may seem clearer.

---

The problem with your solution is `df_c.notnull()` gives a Boolean **dataframe** array, but you want to index via a 1-dimensional array / series. You *could* use:

```
df_c = df[df != '-']
df_c = df_c[df_c.notnull().all(1)]
```

But this is verbose and likely inefficient.

Comment: Thank you, now it works. But what was I doing wrong? because even `df.dropna()` didn't work.

Comment: @Zhang_anlan, I've updated with what you were doing wrong with your initial attempt. I can't replicate "`dropna` didn't work".